# CSS Sprites w/ Browser Colors Enforced

Tags: css, user-interface, cross-browser, css-sprites

A few users have reported problems using my site as a result of combining my use of CSS sprites with their preference to browse with browser colors enforced. The problem appears to be identical in both Firefox and IE. Is there a good solution for this which will enable me to support these users?

Comment: what do you mean by "colors enforced"? How does your code look like?

Comment: For instance, go to the `Options` page in Firefox, then the `Content` tab, then click the `Colors...` button. Then uncheck "Allow pages to set their own colors". IMO it's a horrible browsing experience, but since I've had people using it, I'd like to support them as part of my userbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the browser's background color settings override the image that CSS is setting to create the sprite.

Some clever CSS solved this in a reasonable manner. First, I adjusted the dimensions of the CSS sprites, to reduce their height and width by 2px. Then I added a transparent 1px border. Thus when the page is rendered, the browser draws a border around the perimeter of the CSS-sprited area.

Additionally, I added `color:transparent;` to the CSS to make any contained text transparent. Then each place I use sprites, I add a short bit of text (just a letter or two; enough to indicate a touch of meaning without expanding the site of the element used for the sprite), coupled with a good `title='blah blah...'` description.

**Original CSS:**

```
.sprite1 {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:18px;
   width:18px; 
   background-position:0px 0px;
}
.sprite1:hover {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:18px;
   width:18px; 
   background-position:0px -20px;
}
.sprite2 {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:18px;
   width:18px; 
   background-position:-20px 0px;
}
.sprite2:hover {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:18px;
   width:18px; 
   background-position:-20px -20px;
}
```

**New CSS**

```
.sprite1 {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   width:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   background-position:-1px -1px; //adjusted to account for border
   border: 1px solid transparent; //encloses element in a box that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   color: transparent; //enables including text that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   filter: alpha(opacity = 0); //make transparency work in IE
}
.sprite1:hover {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   width:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   background-position:0px -21px; //adjusted to account for border
   border: 1px solid transparent; //encloses element in a box that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   color: transparent; //enables including text that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   filter: alpha(opacity = 0); //make transparency work in IE
}
.sprite2 {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   width:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   background-position:-21px -1px; //adjusted to account for border
   border: 1px solid transparent; //encloses element in a box that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   color: transparent; //enables including text that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   filter: alpha(opacity = 0); //make transparency work in IE
}
.sprite2:hover {
   background:url(../images/mySprite.png);
   height:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   width:16px; //adjusted to account for border
   background-position:-21px -21px; //adjusted to account for border
   border: 1px solid transparent; //encloses element in a box that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   color: transparent; //enables including text that will only be seen if browser colors are enforced
   filter: alpha(opacity = 0); //make transparency work in IE
}
```